# What am I doing wrong in inserting data to mysql table?

Tags: java, mysql

After executing code I get the `Data saved` message but no data is recorded in my `clients` table? I'm new to databases with Java, What am I doing wrong or how can I fix my code?

```
    String sqlUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/clientinformation";
    String user = "root";
    String pass = "root";
    String name = firstName.getText();
    String lname = lastName.getText();
    String cEmail = email.getText();
    String rate = rateDbl.getText();
    String cUrl = url.getText();
    try {
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(sqlUrl, user, pass);
        PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement("insert into clients 
                values('"+name+"', '"+lname+"', "
                + "'"+cEmail+"', '"+rate+"', '"+cUrl+"')");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data saved!");
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(newClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong

Well, you're building your SQL statement by concatenating values. That leads to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com) - amongst other issues. Fortunately, that hasn't actually created a problem just yet - because you're never *executing* your statement.

You need to:

- Parameterize your SQL, to avoid a SQL injection attack - use question marks for the parameters, and then use `st.setString` to set each parameter:

  ```
  Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(sqlUrl, user, pass);
  PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement(
      "insert into clients values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
  st.setString(1, name);
  st.setString(2, lname);
  st.setString(3, cEmail);
  st.setString(4, rate); // Should this really be a string?
  st.setString(5, cUrl);
  st.executeUpdate();
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data saved!");
  ```
- Call `st.executeUpdate` before you display the dialog box. (Ideally you shouldn't be mixing UI and data access in the same method, but...)

Please make the changes *in that order* though - do *not* just add a call to `st.executeUpdate`, or you've got a horrible security hole in your app.

Comment: How do I Parameterize my SQL?

Comment: I can change the rate to an Int later right?, I get a `SQLException column count doesn't match value count at row 1`.

Comment: @AndresRivera: You'd be better off changing it now - keep your data model as sensible as possible wherever you can. The new error suggests your table contains more columns. It would be worth specifying which fields you're populating in the insert statement: `insert into clients (name, last_name, email, rate, url) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)` for example.

Answer (score 3):

The reason you're not seeing the data is you *prepare* the statement but never *execute* it. Call [`st.execute();`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#execute%28%29) or [`st.executeUpdate();`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate%28%29) to execute it.

---

Separately, though: That code is subject to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) (attacks or otherwise); [fun illustration here](http://xkcd.com/327/). Half the point of prepared statements is to protect against them. Use the parameters that prepared statements give you:

```
PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement("insert into clients values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
int n = 1;
st.setString(n++, name);
st.setString(n++, lname);
st.setString(n++, cEmail);
st.setString(n++, rate);
st.setString(n++, cUrl);
// And then the missing execute
st.execute();
```